# How to add NSLinguisticTagger Scheme if doesn't exist

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, xcode9

I need to get stem of word. So i can't get if lemma scheme doesn't exist for english.

Here's the code that i'm testing available tag schemes :

```
    let tagSchemes = NSLinguisticTagger.availableTagSchemes(forLanguage: "en")
    print(tagSchemes)
```

and this is output:

```
[__C.NSLinguisticTagScheme(_rawValue: TokenType),
     __C.NSLinguisticTagScheme(_rawValue: Language),
     __C.NSLinguisticTagScheme(_rawValue: Script)]
```

Notice that, simulators will return all scheme. My issue is on my device. You can try 'fr' or 'de' except 'en'.

Comment: Does english is your main iphone or mac os language? Have you check its consistency?

Comment: @tereks It is. I finally understand whats going on. Some tag schemes only available for which language you used on your keyboard. Example if you used french keyboard before lemma must be available on your device.

Comment: I've just found that a tag scheme isn't available on my iPhone which does have English as the main language and an English keyboard installed, and had that tag scheme available previously. My phone has been very low on storage space since then, so perhaps the tag scheme gets discarded in that case. A friend who had this problem on his phone said it went away by itself after a day or so, so perhaps the information needed is redownloaded at some point after you try to use a tag scheme. I wish we had confirmation of this so I know what to tell users in that case, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically can't. iOS SDK doesn't exist this feature yet.
Some tag schemes only available for which language used on keyboard as in my question.

Comment: This does not answer the OP.. so this is should be / stay a comment

Comment: @WillVonUllrich why it doesn't. Give me more detail cause its answer but maybe not detailed yet, so i can add them.

Comment: Okay @WillVonUllrich i didn't focus the title cause i asked. But it make sense and i updated my answer good point.